# Fill in Dates by week?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to fill a column week by week including weekends? For example:

> A2 = 12/04/2015 
>   A3 = 19/04/2015 
>   A4 = 26/04/2015....

My current code is as follows:

```
Sub FillDates()
    With Sheet1.Range("A2")
        .Value = DateSerial(2015, 4, 12)
        .AutoFill .Resize(1102, 1), xlFillDays
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried the code for weekdays, months and individual days but this doesn't satisfy what I want, is there a way to fill each corresponding cell in a column with weekly dates?

Comment: Without using AutoFill, I would just add 7 since Excel stores dates as days and that advances a week.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a Sunday's date in `A2` and the next Sunday's date in `A3` then select `A2:A3` and fill down, then there are only Sunday's dates filled because there are ever 7 days difference between Sundays and the default fill behavior will fill series with the difference of the selected cells.

```
Sub FillDates()
 With Sheet1.Range("A2")
        .Value = DateSerial(2015, 4, 12)
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value + 7
        .Resize(2, 1).AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(1102, 1)
 End With
End Sub
```